# Node JS reading local image file and use them in html files

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

For nodemailer.
Tried reading a local image (png) and attaching it to the custom HTML template (img tag).
but the image is not getting displayed in the email. Either it is broken or displaying some random characters.

Tried using readSync, Buffer.from
with formats utf-8, base64, base64url.

Folder structure & sample code

```
src
├── index.ts
├── _assets
│   ├── image.png

const imgData = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/file.png', {encoding: 'base64'});
const htmlTemplate = `
<html><body>
<img src=${img}/>
</body></html>`

await transporter.sendMail({
from: '',
to: '',
subject: '', 
text: '', 
html: imgData});
```

Can't use express static approach, because creating a node package.

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: There are a lot o things you can do wrong in writing email templates manually. Try something like https://maizzle.com/ that build a universal compatible email template you can use with nodemailer. I've got the same issue in one of my projects, which was successfully resolved with maizzlee.

Comment: @Jonathan updated with sample code

Comment: The value of the `src` attribute needs to be a URL, not a base64 encoded string. (You can make a URL from a a base64 encoded string … but you aren't).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs

Comment: @Quentin that was the missing part, thanks
now working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a data url to image source.

```
const imgData = fs.readFileSync('fileee.png', {encoding: 'base64'});
const htmlTemplate = `
<html><body>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,${imgData}"/>
</body></html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the following syntax:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,${img}" />
```

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/embedded-images-in-html-email/

And try the following Base64 code

```
let bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
let img = new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
```